# Storage issue with linked list VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linked-list, console-application

i am using vb.net to create a linked list, and am finding an issue with storage. the second to last value entered is always deleted. i believe this issue is  in the Add() subroutine, but i cant figure out how this is caused, or how to fix it. attached is the code and ss of the console. [console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nXH5.png)

```vb
Module Program

    Structure linkedList
        Dim item As String
        Dim position As Integer
        Dim pointer As Decimal
        Dim isEmpty As Boolean
    End Structure

    Dim tail As Integer
    Dim input As String
    Dim list(30) As linkedList
    Dim index As Integer
    Const head As Integer = 0
    Dim menuChoice As Integer


    Sub Main()
        For i = 0 To list.Length - 1 : list(i).isEmpty = True : Next
        menu()
    End Sub

    Sub menu()

        Do
            Try
                Console.WriteLine("Press 1 to add values, 2 to remove them.")
                menuChoice = Console.ReadLine
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Loop Until menuChoice = 1 Or menuChoice = 2

        Select Case menuChoice
            Case 1
                add()
            Case 2
                remove()
        End Select

    End Sub

    Sub add()

        list(0).position = -1
        list(0).item = "Head"
        index = 1

        Do
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a value to enter into the linked list, or press X to stop: ")
            input = Console.ReadLine

            If input <> "X" And input <> vbNullString Then
                For i = 0 To list.Length - 1


                    If list(i).isEmpty = True Then
                        list(i + 1).item = input
                        list(i + 1).position = index
                        list(i + 1).pointer = index + 1
                        list(i).isEmpty = False

                        Exit For
                    End If

                Next

            End If

            list(0).pointer = findNextAvailable(0)

            If input <> "X" Then : index += 1 : End If

            If input = "X" Then
                tail = index
            End If


        Loop Until input = "X" Or index = 30

        showList()

    End Sub

    Sub remove()

        Dim checked As Boolean = False
        Dim removString As String
        Dim removPos As Integer
        Dim removPoint As Integer
        Dim num1 As Integer

        Do
            Try
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a string to remove from the Linked List:")
                removString = Console.ReadLine.Trim

                For i = 0 To list.Length - 1
                    If list(i).item = removString Then
                        checked = True
                        removPos = i
                        num1 = i - 1
                        list(i).isEmpty = True
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        checked = False
                        list(i).isEmpty = False
                    End If
                Next

            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try

        Loop Until checked = True

        list(removPos).item = vbNullString
        list(removPos).pointer = fixPointer(num1)
        list(num1).pointer = findPos(removPos)

        showList()

    End Sub

    Function findPos(start As Integer) As Integer

        Dim check As Boolean
        Dim num1 As Integer

        For i = start To list.Length - 1
            If list(i).item <> vbNullString Then
                check = True
                num1 = i - 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If check = True Then
            Return num1
        Else
            Return vbNullString
        End If

    End Function

    Function findNextAvailable(startPoint As Integer) As Integer

        Dim nextAvailableTrue As Boolean
        Dim num1 As Integer

        For i = startPoint To 0 Step -1

            If list(i).item <> vbNullString Then
                nextAvailableTrue = True
                num1 = i
                Exit For
            End If

        Next
        If nextAvailableTrue Then
            Return num1 + 1
        Else
            Return startPoint + 1
        End If
    End Function

    Function fixPointer(r As Integer) As Integer

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim check As Boolean = False

        Do
            If list(i).item <> vbNullString Then
                check = True
            End If
            i += 1
        Loop Until check = True
        For x = 0 To list.Length - 1
            If list(x).pointer <> vbNull And list(x).item = vbNullString Then
                list(x).pointer = vbNull
            End If
        Next

        list(r).pointer = list(i).position

        Return list(r).pointer

    End Function

    Sub showList()
        Dim lastPosition As Integer = 0

        For x = 0 To list.Length - 1
            If list(x).isEmpty Then
                list(x).pointer = 0
                list(x).position = x
            End If

            If list(x).isEmpty = False Then
                lastPosition = list(x).position
            End If
        Next

        list(lastPosition).item = vbNullString
        list(lastPosition).pointer = 0.0

        For i = 0 To list.Length - 1
            Console.WriteLine($"{list(i).position} ¦ {list(i).item} ¦ {list(i).pointer}")
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
        menu()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Are you aware of the .net framework's LinkedList class? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=net-6.0

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict and correct the errors it points out.

Comment: In the findPos method, you can't return vbNullString because the Function is returning an Integer.

Comment: Variables of type Decimal cannot be null unless declared as nullable.